# MongoDB cannot sort the _id?

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple order table in mongoDB

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(2), 
    "bar" : "Maggie Choos Bar" 
},
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(3), 
    "bar" : "Corona Bar"
{
```

I want to find the BIGGEST "_id" number in the table

```
db.getCollection("order").find({}).sort({"$_id":-1}).limit(1);
```

But no matter if I sort 1 or -1 I keep getting the result with _id : 2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field name prefixed with a dollar sign, like `$_id`, is for references in an aggregation pipeline.  For a sort document, use just the field name:

```
db.getCollection("order").find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: That did the trick! - Thanks!.  I didnt know $field was only for references :)